# PHP: Get all parameters from the url without the file id

Tags: php

I want to extract all used parameters of a link as a text string. Example:

```
$link2 = http://example.com/index.html?song=abcdefg;
```

When using the above link `$param` should give out all the parameters '?song=abcdefg'. Unfortunately I do not know the id `index.html` nor the parameters and their respective data values.

As much as I am informed there is the function `$_GET`, which creates an array, but I need a string.

Comment: Check out [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
$link2 = 'http://example.com/index.html?song=abcdefg';
$param = '?' . parse_url($link2, PHP_URL_QUERY);

echo $param;
// ?song=abcdefg
```

Answer (score 0):

Many librairies exist to parse url, you can use this one for an exemple :

https://github.com/thephpleague/uri

```
use League\Uri\Schemes\Http as HttpUri;

$link2 = 'http://example.com/index.html?song=abcdefg';
$uri = HttpUri::createFromString($link2);
// then you can access the query
$query = $uri->query;
```

You also can try this one :
https://github.com/jwage/purl

Answer (score 0):

A weird way to do this is

```
$link2 = 'http://example.com/index.html?song=abcdefg';
$param = strstr($link2, "?");
echo $param // ?song=abcdefg
```

`strstr($link2, "?")` will get everything after the first position of `?`; including the leading `?`

Answer (score 0):

you can loop over the get array and parse it into a string:

```
$str = "?"
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { 
    $temp = $key . "=". $value . "&";
    $str .= $temp
}
rtrim($str, "&")//remove leading '&'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use http_build_query() method

```
if ( isset ($_GET))
{
    $params =  http_build_query($_GET);     
}

// echo $params should return "song=abcdefg";
```

Comment: Did not work, because output was "id=index.html&song=abcdefg"

Comment: "id=index.html" is part of the params sent in the url. (url is probably rewritten)
What exactly are you expecting to receive?